# show listview item after restarting application

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview

There are two edittexts and one button in my app. One is for id and another is for date of birth. User can put id & dob and then click add button.

This id and date of birth must be exist in database. If user click add button, user's id and name will be showed in a listview.

Here I can easily retrieve json data and show it in a listview, But when I close application and restart application those added items erased.

How can I solve this? Suppose in facebook, if we add friend in our friend list, it never erased after closing app. Here is my code link:

```
 code here: https://ideone.com/LM4HzE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1.Better to store the Data in SQlite Or Shared preference
 Retreived data should be stored in Shared preference or Sqlite the data will not be Erased otherwise the data will be erased,


    Store:
      SharedPreferences app_preferencesnew = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferencesnew.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("bfirsttime", true);
             editor.putString("selected", selected);
            editor.commit();

     Retreive:
         String userId = app_preferencesnew.getString("selected", "");
```

Comment: I have already tried shared preference but can not understand how to solve. Here is my code:  https://ideone.com/LM4HzE

Comment: put key value should be same ,where you put id name value

Comment: studentID.setText(prefs.getString("autoSave1", ""));
        DOB.setText(prefs.getString("autoSave2", ""));                                editor.putString(autoSave1, id);
                                editor.putString(autoSave2, dob);

Answer (score 0):

There is two option if you want data for longer period

1. shared preference (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm)
2. SQLite (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/)

Store data first in sqlite or shared preference then load in listview from this